# How to implement subqueries in cube.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregation, cube.js

I'm struggling to see how I would represent the following type of postgres SQL query in a cube.js schema:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(tpp.net_total_amount) > 0 THEN
        SUM(tpp.net_total_amount) / COUNT(tpp.net_total_amount)
    ELSE
        NULL
    END AS average_spend_per_customer
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(ts.total_amount) AS net_total_amount
        FROM
            postgres.transactions AS ts
        WHERE
            ts.transaction_date >= '2020-11-01' AND
            ts.transaction_date < '2020-12-01'
        GROUP BY
            ts.customer_id,
            ts.event_id
    ) AS tpp
;
```

I had the feeling that pre-aggregations might be what I'm after, but that doesn't seem to be the case after looking into them.  I can get a list of total amount spent per customer per event with the following schema:

```
cube(`TransactionTotalAmountByCustomerAndEvent`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM postgres.transactions`,

  joins: {

  },

  measures: {
    sum: {
      sql: `SUM(total_amount)`,
      type: `number`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    eventId: {
      sql: `event_id`,
      type: `string`
    },

    customerId: {
      sql: `customer_id`,
      type: `string`
    },

    transactionDate: {
      sql: `transaction_date`,
      type: `time`
    }
  },

  preAggregations: {
    customerAndEvent: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [sum],
      dimensionReferences: [customerId, eventId]
    }
  }
});
```

But that is really just giving me the output of the inner SELECT statement grouped by customer and event.  How do I query the cube to get the average customer spend per event figure I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to model the dataset as two different cubes, `Customers` and `Transactions`. You'll then need to set up a join between the cubes and then create a special dimension with the `subQuery` property set to `true`. I've included an example below to help you understand:

```
cube('Transactions', {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM postgres.transactions`,

  measures: {
    spend: {
      sql: `total_amount`,
      type: `number`,
    },
  },

  dimensions: {
    eventId: {
      sql: `event_id`,
      type: `string`
    },

    customerId: {
      sql: `customer_id`,
      type: `string`
    },

    transactionDate: {
      sql: `transaction_date`,
      type: `time`
    },
  },
})

cube('Customers', {
  sql: `SELECT customer_id FROM postgres.transactions`,

  joins: {
    Transactions: {
      relationship: `hasMany`,
      sql: `${Customers}.id = ${Transactions}.customerId`
    }
  },

  measures: {
    averageSpend: {
      sql: `${spendAmount}`,
      type: `avg`,
    },
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `customer_id`,
      type: `string`
    },
    spendAmount: {
      sql: `${Transactions.spend}`,
      type: `number`,
      subQuery: true
    },
  }
})
```

You can find more information on the [Subquery page on the documentation](https://cube.dev/docs/subquery#top)